# How to install/update the latest version of CURL on WIN10?

Tags: windows, curl

My current version is 7.55.1, and I also downloaded the new version of curl (7.79.1).
However, after I add its directory in the system environment path and check the version of curl by using 'curl --version', it still shows me the old version.
Can anyone give some ideas to help me update/install the new version of curl on win10?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

To whoever is looking for this, 
Copy the link to your curl bin folder 
Add it to system level environmental variables 
Move it up using the "Move up" button to appear before system 32 path. If you dont, the default version that comes with windows will be taken by the system.

[image: Screenshop]

Comment: This is a nice solution but isn't there any way to remove or update curl in system32 folder? I can not be sure that the curl.exe where located in system32 might occur any problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have installed curl in C:\Program Files\curl-7.79.1-win64-mingw\bin

and your system environment path point to  C:\Users\curl-7.79.1-win64-mingw\bin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).